# Thread pool Implementation using Boost::thread class

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I want to implement thread pool using `boost::thread` class.

I am able to create the threads using below line.

```
boost::thread Consumer_1(consume);
```

where `consumer_1` is thread and consume is the function bound to it.

Above statement starts the thread as soon as it gets executed.

Now I just want to create the thread and do the binding run time.

I have not yet discovered the `boost` method to delay this binding.

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding *can't* be done later. For principal reasons—a thread of execution has to be executing something.

What you need to do is create a function, that will take jobs, represented as `boost::function`, from a queue and execute them. Than run this function in one or more threads.

I am not sure there is a thread-safe queue, but you can always use a regular `std::deque` with `boost::condition_variable` for waking up the threads and `boost::mutex` for locking the deque.

You might want to look at [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/libs/asio/) too. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12880954/201725).

Comment: +1 For suggesting Asio. You probably don't want to use your own threadpool in production code. If you have to, check out Williams' 'C++ Concurrency in Action' book which has a whole chapter on the topic, discussing the many many things that you can do wrong.